# Concurrent frequency counter - concurrency issue

Tags: java, concurrency

I would like to create a concurrent frequency counter class in Java.

It's about that once a request is processed (by processRequest method), the code checks the request's type (an integer) and counts how many requests have been processed (grouped by the request's type) from a given time. The processRequest method will be called by multiple threads in the same time.

There are two other methods:

- clearMap(): It will be called by one thread in every 3 hours and clears the whole map.
- getMap(): It can be called in any time by a webservice and returns an immutable copy of the current state of the frequency map.

See below my initial plan to implement that.

```
public class FrequencyCounter {

     private final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,Long> frequencenyMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

     public void processRequest(Request request){
         frequencenyMap.merge(request.type, 0L, (v, d) -> v+1);
     }

     public void clearMap(){
         frequencenyMap.clear();
     }

     public Map<Integer,Long> getMap(){
         return ImmutableMap.copyOf(frequencenyMap);
     }
}
```

I checked the documentation of ConcurrentHashMap and it tells that the merge method is performed atomically.

So once the clear() method starts to clear the hash buckets of the map (locking as per hash bucket), it can't be invoked when another thread is between getting the value of the frequency map and incrementing its value in the processRequest method because the merge method is executed atomically.

Am I right?
Does my above plan seem to be fine?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Replace `Long` with [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html)

Comment: Are you sure you have your arguments to `merge` correct?

Comment: @Andreas given that merge is atomic, why?

Comment: @AndyTurner Less boxing. Probably less chance of collision too.

Comment: The title says "concurrency issue" - what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, replace `Long` with [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html).

Second, use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

```
 private final Map<Integer, AtomicLong> frequencyMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

 public void processRequest(Request request){
     frequencyMap.computeIfAbsent(request.type, k -> new AtomicLong())
                 .incrementAndGet();
 }
```

There are a few reasons why I believe this is a better solution:

1. The code in the question uses boxed objects, i.e. `(v, d) -> v+1` is really `(Long v, Long d) -> Long.valueOf(v.longValue() + 1)`.

   That code generates extra garbage, which can be avoided by using `AtomicLong`.

   The code here only allocates one object per key, and doesn't require any extra allocations to increment the counter, e.g. it will still only be the one object even if counter goes to the millions.
2. The unboxing, adding 1, boxing operation will likely take slightly longer than the tightly coded `incrementAndGet()` operation, increasing the likelyhood of a collision, requiring a re-try in the `merge` method.
3. Code "purity". Using a method that takes a "value", which is then entirely ignored, seems wrong to me. It is unnecessary code noise.

These are of course my opinions. You can make your own decision, but I think this code clarifies the purpose, i.e. to increment a `long` counter, in a fully thread-safe way.

Comment: You should explain why this is preferable to OP's approach. And why `AtomicLong` rather than `LongAdder`?

Comment: Why use an `AtomicLong` in conjunction with a `ConcurrentHashMap`? Wouldn't it be better to create your own `MutableLong` class that isn't thread-safe?

Comment: @JacobG. The entire point is for the code to be thread-safe, so why would you discard the freely available thread-safe `AtomicLong` for a homegrown class that isn't thread-safe. Kind of defeats the point, don't you think?

Comment: @Andreas The point I was trying to make was, OP is already using a `ConcurrentHashMap` with atomic operations. It would still be thread safe without the overhead of an `AtomicLong`, assuming they stick to those atomic operations.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why I should use AtomicLong instead of Long if the merge/computeIfAbsent methods are executed atomically.

Comment: @Andreas, Thank you for your answer, but I think it should be:

requencyMap.computeIfAbsent(request.type, key -> new AtomicLong(1)).incrementAndGet();
Do you agree?

Comment: @user2693979 no. That would mean the count is 2 after you see a key for the first time.

Comment: @AndyTurner, Sorry I missed the number.
So I think it should be: requencyMap.computeIfAbsent(request.type, key -> new AtomicLong(0)).incrementAndGet(); ---> instead of frequencyMap.computeIfAbsent (request.type,AtomicLong::new).incrementAndGet();
Am I right?

Comment: @AndyTurner: Also, I think the computeIfAbsent and the incrementAndGet are two separate but atomic method call, so any unwanted thing can happen between them.

Comment: @user2693979 no bad thing can happen between the cia and increment calls. Badness would occur if two calls created different AtomicLongs (no, because of atomicity of cia), or if two increments stomp the other's increment (no, because of atomicity of AtomicLong).